# Why http cookies are automatically sent to the server upon a http requests and CSRF

Tags: cookies, csrf, cors

On the client side, a http request sent from webpage A that targets website B will cause all cookies belonging to Website B to be sent to B (even when A does not belong to B).

I do not understand why the cookies behavior has been designed this way. Isn't it obviously insure and the root reason behind CSRF (cross-site request forgery)?

I know nowadays "same-site cookie" is on the way. But I want to know what was the motivation of the old insecure design.

Comment: i don't see how it's insecure given the other protection mechanisms in place; they've always said to use POST for anything half-way important.

Comment: @dandavis: CSRF attacks aren't prevented by using POST. An attacker could create an auto-submitting form pointing to the vulnerable page.

Comment: @BenoitEsnard: true, but that's a much harder attack than a mere link-based one i could link from here and have stopped by POST requirements. My main point still stands: there's plenty of arrows in the W3 quiver to prevent such things. How many breaches are done by user agents that respect such rules (as opposed to CURL et al)? CSRF is one of the most-understood attacks, and the least-useful in that it's trivial to prevent.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#History), the concept of cookies comes from Lou Montulli in June 1994. The HTTP protocol was still very young.

Since HTTP lacks some fundamental security features, such as encryption, I guess security wasn't their priority. I also doubt that any of the people working at that time could have anticipated that HTTP would be so wildly used nowadays, even by evil actors.

It's way easier to look back at all the vulnerabilities / specs flaws we found in the latest 20 years, that to anticipate them all in the first place.

As you've said, [the SameSite cookie attribute](https://caniuse.com/#feat=same-site-cookie-attribute) is on the way to fix that flaw. Until its support by browsers, developers should use [standard CSRF mitigations techniques](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: samesite cookies would kill advertiser spying, so as long as your browser's maker sells ads (3/4 do), don't hold your breath on this getting implemented.

Comment: @dandavis: Well, Google sells a lot of ads, and have implemented it more than a year ago, so I guess it's just a matter of time before other browser vendors do the same. But you're right, we'll need to support older browsers for years before migrating.

Comment: well that's good news (to me) about google. i'm not sure about how it handles WebWorkers, but the rest seemed to be a good idea...